# encoding several variables into a byte

Tags: solidity, bytes, encoding

I want to define a byte256 and I want to assign different sections of the byte to different variables, any literature or guidance is appreciated.

for further clarity I want to do something like

```
variable 0 = address 
variable 1 = address
variable 2 = value 
variable 3 = address
variable 5 = address
variable 4 = address
```

now Id want to do:

```
byte50:
    bit 0-10=  variable 0
    bit 10-20=  variable 1
    bit 20-30=  variable 2
    bit 30-40=  variable 3
    bit 40-50=  variable 4
```

I realize the above may not be correct at all(I'm just trying to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve). I would like to know firstly whether its feasible and if so how I should go on about it.

I have no idea how to handle this so I'd appreciate any pointers

Comment: Generally speaking, you are looking for a left shift operator. E.g., let's imagine I want to encode two `uint8` variables in an `uint16` one. Let-s denote these variables `x_1`, `x_2` and `x_all`, respectively. `x_all = x_1 << 8 + x_2` (It is equivalent to `x_all = x_1 * (2**8) + x_2`
(N.B. an address in Ethereum is a 160-bit (20 bytes) length variable). In this question you can find something similar with riight shift operator https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61826/how-to-extract-function-signature-from-msg-data/61839#61839

Answer (score 0):

You can find libraries useful for that. Search about memory optimization in Solidity. I’ll do for you as well and when found I’ll post the reference here.

It is a well known approach, not particularly efficient if managed in Solidity, easy to realize using assembly.

Found: read this https://link.medium.com/9cq5nlXqKT

In short it is suggested to write one function which access in writing and one which access in reading using a simple assembly in order to avoid to mask and shift. It is easy to do.